# Why vertical scrollbar doesn't appear although vertical overflow is set?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar that sometimes is bigger than the main page, I try to set the vertical overflow but the vertical scroll bar still doesn't appear.

```
/**
 * Created by eduard on 07.01.2016.
 */
console.log("Height 1 ", sidebar_height);

if ($(window).height() < sidebar_height + 35) {
    $('body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
    //$("#sidebar").css('overflowY', 'auto');
    console.log("Scrollbar should appear", $(window).height() - sidebar_height);
}
else {
    console.log("Scrollbar should not appear", $(window).height() - sidebar_height);
}
```

Why vertical scrollbar doesn't appear although vertical overflow is set?

Comment: Try setting it to scroll instead of auto.

Comment: @Styphon setting it to `scroll` still doesn't make the scroll bar to appear

Comment: Do you actually have a fixed height?

Comment: I just learned that I need to have a fixed height to set the the scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the value to `scroll` should do the trick:

```
$('body').css('overflowY', 'scroll');
```

It essentially forces a scrollbar to appear regardless of overflowing content or not.

EDIT - Alternatively, try adding a class when the window height goes below:

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lhwfjk6/

I've simplified the examle slightly for this case. You'll need to resize the actual browser window.

**jQuery:**

```
/**
 * Created by eduard on 07.01.2016.
 */
console.log("Height 1 ", sidebar_height);

if ($(window).height() < 300) {
    $('.content').addClass('scrollbar');
    //$("#sidebar").css('overflowY', 'auto');
    console.log("Scrollbar should appear", $(window).height() - sidebar_height);
}
else {
    console.log("Scrollbar should not appear", $(window).height() - sidebar_height);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollbar {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```